# Stop everything in an activity after leaving it

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm beginner and working on an android app.
I want to stopp every process and everything of an activity when I leave it.

For example:
I'm actually in "**first_activity.class**"

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(Con_send_code_sms_accounte_recover.this, "in first activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

If I leave **first_activity.class** before 10 seconds and to go to **second_activity.class**, I dont want to see the toast message in my actual(second_activity.class) activity.

How could I do that ?

**Edit:**
I have done that toast message to simplify my question.

**To be more clear:**

That first_activity.class contains one AsyncTask request. It is that AsyncTask  request I want to stop when I change activity.

Here is a part of that request:

```
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tel_recover_accounte", tel_recover_accounte));
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpParams param = httpClient.getParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(param, 15000);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpResponse.getEntity();
                str =  EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
            return str;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         ....
        }
    }
```

I also want to stop everything that is processing in that first_activity when i leave it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Toast` is special because it will remain displayed even after the activity is hidden. This is because it uses a Service. I This won't happen with `Snackbar` for example.

But you can keep the instance of Toast you create with `makeText` in order to be able to hide it when the activity is closed.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toast toast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create a toast to be used later.
        toast = Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Hello world!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            toast.show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Activity goes to background, hide toast.
        super.onPause();
        toast.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page);


        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in first activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);

    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

cancel your toast by this function before exiting the activity:

```
public static void cancelToast() {
    if (null != toast) {
      toast.cancel();
    }
  }
```